# Как суммировать числа с точкой в excel?

Tags: excel

Я вставила в столбец *A* числа из текстового файла, установила для этого столбца формат *Number*:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и пытаюсь суммировать значения в столбце формулой:

```
=SUM(A1:A6)
```

Однако получаю в результате *0,00*. Я предполагаю, что это из-за того, что в формате *Number* как разделитель для числа указана запятая, а не точка. Как сделать так, чтобы в файле *excel* можно было суммировать числа с разделителем-точкой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для случаев, если замена потребуется не разовая - вариант с использованием функций листа.

Перед суммированием заменить разделитель:

```
=СУММ(--ПОДСТАВИТЬ(0&A1:A6;".";","))

=СУММПРОИЗВ(--ПОДСТАВИТЬ(0&A1:A6;".";","))
```

Первая (с *СУММ*) - формула массива, вводится с помощью трех клавиш - *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*. Для второй массивный ввод не требуется.

*0&A1:A6* - добавление нуля исключает ошибку при пустом значении ячейки указанного диапазона.

Бинарное отрицание преобразует текстовую запись в число.

Бывает, что в таких значениях разделителем разрядов служит запятая (пример: *1,235.77*). В этом случае сначала меняем запятую на пусто и только после этого точку на запятую:

```
=СУММПРОИЗВ(--ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(0&A1:A6;",";);".";","))
```

Answer (score 1):

Я решила этот вопрос по-другому: с помощью **Ctrl+H** заменила все точки на запятые и суммировала числа той же формулой.